# Combining Predicates within Lambda Expression

Tags: java, lambda, predicate

This is a two part question.

I have a boolean field and several String[] fields and I need to evaluate predicates for each one.

The following code gets interfaces for each device. I then want to evaluate those interfaces based on the predicates.

1. Is there a more efficient way to do it?
2. .filter(predicates.stream().reduce(Predicate::or) gives this error:
   [image: incompatible types:invalid method reference] that I'm unsure how to resolve.

   ```
       parentReference.getDevices().stream().parallel().filter(ASA_PREDICATE).forEach((device) -> {
       List<Predicate<? super TufinInterface>> predicates = new ArrayList();

       if (iName != null) {
           Predicate< ? super TufinInterface> iNameFilter = myInterface -> Arrays.stream(iName)
                   .allMatch(input -> myInterface.getName().toLowerCase().contains(input.toLowerCase()));
           predicates.add(iNameFilter);
       }
       if (ipLow != null) {
           Predicate< ? super TufinInterface> ipLowFilter = myInterface -> Arrays.stream(ipLow)
                   .allMatch(input -> myInterface.getName().toLowerCase().contains(input.toLowerCase()));
           predicates.add(ipLowFilter);
       }
       if (ip != null) {
           Predicate< ? super TufinInterface> ipFilter = myInterface -> Arrays.stream(ip)
                   .allMatch(input -> myInterface.getName().toLowerCase().contains(input.toLowerCase()));
           predicates.add(ipFilter);
       }
       if (zone != null) {
           Predicate< ? super TufinInterface> zoneFilter = myInterface -> Arrays.stream(zone)
                   .allMatch(input -> myInterface.getName().toLowerCase().contains(input.toLowerCase()));
           predicates.add(zoneFilter);
       }            

       try {
           ArrayList<TufinInterface> tufinInterfaces = Tufin.GET_INTERFACES(parentReference.user, parentReference.password, parentReference.hostName, device)
                   .stream()
                   .filter(predicates.stream().reduce(Predicate::or)
                           .orElse(t->true)).parallel().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<TufinInterface>::new));
           interfaces.addAll(tufinInterfaces);
       } catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException | JSONException | Tufin.IncompatibleDeviceException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(InterfaceCommand.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }

   });
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stream has a function called [anyMatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) that can clean up your filter a bit.

```
ArrayList<TufinInterface> tufinInterfaces = Tufin.GET_INTERFACES(parentReference.user, parentReference.password, parentReference.hostName, device)
                .stream()
                .filter(s -> predicates.stream().anyMatch(pred -> pred.test(s)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I was attempting to use reduce. Is anyMatch prefered?